# Why is the trivial $FH$-module $V$ isomorphic to $\langle \frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{h\in H}h\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, $V$ the trivial $FH$-module, where $F$ is a field and $FH$ denotes the group algebra of $H$ over $F$. Then $V\cong \langle e_H\rangle$, where $e_H=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{h\in H}h$ and $\langle e_H\rangle$ denotes the $FH$-submodule of $FH$ generated by the element $e_H$, and $FG\otimes_{FH}\langle e_H\rangle\cong FG\cdot e_H$? May someone give me a note for these two questions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as $|H|\ne0$ in $F$, your expression $S$ satisfies $h\cdot S=S$ for all $h\in H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write $g\in G$ as $g = \sum_{t\in T} th_t$ where $T$ is a set of coset representatives of $G$ w.r.t. $H$ and $h_t\in H$.
Then
$g\otimes e_H = \sum_{t\in T} t\otimes h_t e_H$ by the linearity of the tensor operation and $\sum_{t\in T} t\otimes h_t e_H = \sum_{t\in T} t\otimes e_H\in FG\otimes_{FH}\langle e_H\rangle $ due to the trivial action.

Similarly, $g\cdot e_H = \sum_{t\in T} t e_H \in FG\cdot e_H$.

Comment: Thank you very much!